# How to track changes for a has_many through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a many-to-many relationship between `Teams` and `Colors`, how do I do tell if there are `teams_colors` (join table) records that are not yet persisted to the database?

```
class Team
  has_many :teams_colors
  has_many :colors, through: :team_colors
```

For example, in the following scenario:

- `team_one` is not persisted to the database
- `color_red` is persisted to the database.

```
team_one << color_red
```

I'm looking for some sort of `#changes` method that I can call to see the record that will be added to the `teams_colors` table after `team_one.save!` is called.

I have seen some suggestions that you can look for changes on each color like `team_one.colors.first.changes` but this doesn't work because the color records are already persisted since it is only the join table record that is not persisted.

Comment: I'm not sure, but there may be something useful in [active_model/dirty.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activemodel/lib/active_model/dirty.rb)